# How do I extract and replace a substring with a different value

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have the following string: "Using the following data [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] status is connected"

What I want to do is replace [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] with data retrieved from an XML file. So I need to first extract [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] into its own string and then I already have a method to query the XML, but furthermore then what I need to do once I've retrieved the value is to then replace it into the original string.

There's another curve ball, the structure wont always be:

```
[EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]
```

it might have extra "nodes" like:

```
[SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]
```

or

```
[Region][SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]
```

As long as I can extract this pattern from the original string i can grab the data from it. As I mentioned above what I then need to be able to do is then replace "[SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]" with the data I've retrieved. So for example it might be something as simple as "UKUser" that gets returned so the new string would end up being "Using the following data UKUser status is connected"

Any guidance would be appreciated, i'm sure there are many ways of doing this.

Update

Heres and example

```
string myQuery = "Using the following data [SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]";

string xmlQuery = RetrieveXMLQuery(myQuery);

//So now I want xmlQuery to be "[SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]"
//XML query now gets executed
string xmlResult = RetrieveXMLValue(xmlQuery);
//xmlResult would now be "UKUser"

//Now what I want to do is take the string "Using the following data [SystemTest][EnvironmentVar][TestAccount]" and replace the nodes with UKUser is it becomes "Using the following data UKUser"
//Remember that the number of nodes and the sequence wont always be the same...
```

Comment: Can't you simply do `str = str.Replace("[TestAccount]", "new data here");` ? Do you need to use regular expression?

Comment: That would only replace the TestAccount the rest of it would stay within the string. i'll update my question with a bit more information now.

Comment: The rest of it? Run multiple replace calls after each other, that should replace one keyword at a time. Granted, it's probably not performance optimal, but neither is a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you want to replace the "extra nodes" too, when they exist:

```
string input = "Using the following data [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] status is connected";
string newData = "UKUser";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\[.*\])", newData);
Console.WriteLine(output);  // Using the following data UKUser status is connected
```

Comment: The problem with this is if the sequence changes then this wont work. At runtime the string could be different. Im looking for a solution that will work for any string.

Comment: Very good this works nicely for replacing the string. I'm happy with that. Could I use a similar method for extracting [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] (or similar) from the original string?

Comment: sure. that would be Regex.Match with the same pattern

Comment: An upvote and a tick for you sir, this does exactly what I want it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could break out the tokens and process individually;

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\[[A-Za-z]+\])", delegate(Match match)
       {
            switch (match.Groups[1].Value)
            {
                case "[SystemTest]":
                    return (string)SomeXml.Element("SystemTestNode");

                case "[TestAccount]":
                    return "123456";

                default:
                    return "";
            }
       });
```

Comment: Makes sense but Imagine that the values between [] are nodes in an XML file. I dont always know what they are going to be. So with this approach id need to map them all out.

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern always starts with [ and ends with ] you could easily do this with just using substring.

```
string original = "Using the following data [EnvironmentVar][TestAccount] status is connected";
string replacementText = "UKUser";

string newString = original.Substring(0, original.IndexOf("[")) + replacementText + original.Substring(original.LastIndexOf("]")+1);
```

Comment: An interesting approach. I could certainly use this. The pattern will always start with [ and end with ]

Comment: I haven't tested, but I'm guessing this would also be more efficient than using regex. You would also want to add some error handling or validation to make sure the brackets exist.